# Cannot read property 'FIXED' of undefined cast.framework

Tags: chromecast, google-cast

I receive this error when trying to cast on google chromecast  :

> [cast.framework.EventTarget] Handler for sessionstatechanged event failed: TypeError: Cannot read property 'FIXED' of undefined

Yesterday everything was working perfect. Today I receive this error, and when I try to get object property "playerState" it has null value.

Do you have any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to have been resolved in this [github forum](https://github.com/xat/castnow/issues/80). What the users did was just restart the Chromecast. If you haven't changed anything in the code, then perhaps, the chromecast is at fault.

> "I try many stuff nothing was working... And just restarting the
>   chromecast solved this"